# AngularJS ng-repeat data from Parse

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parsing

I'm developing backend with Parse. I can get data from Parse but I can't show with ng-repeat with AngularJS.

```
app.controller('QuestionsController',['$scope', function ($scope) {
 var query = new Parse.Query(_Categories);
 query.find().done(function(data){
     $scope.Categories = data;
     console.log($scope.Categories);
 });

 $scope.Logout = function(){
     Parse.User.logOut();
     window.location.href = '#';
 }}]);
```

I'm using ngRoute and this HTML codes

```
        <div class="menu">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="bars"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="Category in Categories"><a href="#">{{Category.Name}}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I can see data on Console but I can't show on page.

Comment: Can you set a random scope variable in your controller then display it in your HTML? Double check the controller is actually controlling your html.

Comment: When i set the static variable to scope it's working. Example $scope.Categories = [{ Name: 'Test' },{ Name: 'Test 2' }]; this code is working

Comment: perhaps your controller is not being correctly applied to your template, please make a quick check by adding `$scope.test` on your controller and `{{test}}` on your html

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. Controller codes is

```
    var query = new Parse.Query(_Categories);
    query.find({
        success: function(data){
            $scope.Categories = data;
            $scope.$apply();
        }
    });
```

And i wrote this code on HTMl

```
            <div class="bars"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="cat in Categories">
                    <a href="#" >{{cat.get('Name')}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```